# What is this error? ctrl+Alt+t is also not working

Tags: command-line

> Error:GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking your dbus which can be thought as an service talking to different programs simultaneoulsy and syncing them whenever necessary.You can get more information here [d-bus wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus).

An simple example could be your usb modem connecting itself to your system via USB serial mode, then d-bus tells your serial mode aka ttyUSB0 to make yourself available to modem-manager.Thus now modem-manager is now able to communicate to your USB modem via d-bus. So after this you can connect to internet via modem-manager. You can easily see there is a co-operation between serial process controller(to manage serial connections),ip host controller(to control ppp0),udev rules(to mount your device as a network card),D-bus(desktop-bus),modem-manager(network-manager applet to control modems).

Your d-bus happens to be fork for GNOME i.e GDBus.
Now based on the error it actually means that there is no process/sub-process associate it with,So simply it had to terminate. or there could be the parent process terminated before the child process began.

In your case the terminal is not able to be called due to error establishing a connection.So could you instead try some another terminal like Xterm,terminology,etc to see wheter those are able to work or not. Then try launching your main terminal from the menu.If your main menu launches then there may be a key binding issue so upgrading might help.

Think it this way. You dialled a number using your phone.Your telecom operator established a connection via the BASE_station (BTS) exchange mechanism.Then it forwarded to your called number.While doing so the BTS failed in your area due to some reason.You got network issue and the call was disconnected. During the same time your destination number got a ring (forwarded by your exchange) and got dissconnected.

Comment: Whatever I install, I'm getting this error. Some apps are not working properly. Is there a way to fix it @SIDDHARTH

Comment: Could you exactly confirm that which distributution of Ubuntu do you use.It can be UBUNTU Gnome(gnome 3),Ubuntu Mate(Mate fork of gnome2), or something else,Can be seen by "lsb_release" if terminal is working .  High chances are that your gnome d-bus was not configured properly so "sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade;sudo apt dist-upgrade" might fix it.       One more question can you use python programming . If so then I will provide you a python dbus program to try to get what`s the main issue.

Comment: Accidentally I uninstalled python3.5 and along with it various application got uninstalled like chrome,unity,Ubuntu-desktop and many more..

Comment: Yes I can use Python @SIDDHARTH

Comment: That may be the cause as dbus and apt are mainly controlled by python (GUI ones not the terminal).   Anyway use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter to TTY mode and then install python3  once again. Once installed reboot the system by issuing "sudo reboot".  Then try opening terminal again. Ctrl+Alt+F7/F8 will revert to normal mode from TTY mode

Comment: Try from one of the example from the tutorial https://georgemuraruc.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/d-bus-tutorial-for-python/ .  If it works then something entirely else is causing the issue. If it fails then install the d-bus interface for your system

Comment: Thanks for you help. Everything is fine now with my system. Thanks again